# How do I run disconnect-viserver with no prompt in PowerCLI

Tags: vmware, powercli

How can I disable the prompt when using the following cmdlet to disconnect from a server in PowerCLI? The help file shows a -Confirm option, which I don't use, so I'm inferring from this that without it, there should be NO prompt, but I still get prompted?

disconnect-viserver -server MyServer

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
disconnect-viserver -confirm:$false
```

As you notice, omitting the Confirm parameter is equivalent to `-Confirm:$true`

Comment: I had been trying the standard powershell `-Force` but getting nowhere. I wonder if this is a PowerCLI specific switch.